# How to deduplicate nested data in es5.6

Tags: python

The data example is as follows：

```json
{
  "_id": "AYc1Xk4JMTFNgTcwpES6",
  "_source": {
    "task_id": "03fe407b9754506a28dbaf71d01c5cf41dd65d479cc7198c19bd7efe",
    "sha1": "fdbd6026f6a4061f3a83f6242f66ae72",
    "detect_status": 1,
    "malicious_family": [
      {
        "score": 1,
        "name": "gameteaspy",
        "analysis_engine": [
          "RAS"
        ],
        "data_source": [
          "qax"
        ]
     },
      {
        "score": 1,
        "name": "malware",
        "analysis_engine": [
          "RAS"
        ],
        "data_source": [
          "qax"`your text`
        ]
      },
      {
        "score": 0.9718849643766059,
        "name": "zbot",
        "analysis_engine": [
          "ML"
        ],
        "data_source": [
          "qax"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

There are two pieces of data above in my es，where `malicious_family` is nested type. I now need to aggregate `malicious_family.name,` and judge whether `malicious_family.sorce` is greater than 1.0, and perform sha1 deduplication. What should I do?

Below is the expected result

```py
[{'name': 'gameteaspy', 'sample_count': 1}, {'name': 'malware', 'sample_count': 1}]
```